# Redirecting my websites index page to another page in my website?

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I don't know how to redirect my **index page** to **another page** like when you go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it redirects to [www.example.com/home](http://www.example.com/home). I use GitHub pages for this how can I do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: doesnt need to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Redirecting to https://example.com/</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://www.example.com/home">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/home">
```

Try putting this in your `<head></head>` in your index.html file.